# Best way to solve $ z^{2} + i \cdot z = 0 $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

What is the best way to solve $ z^{2} + i \cdot z = 0 $ ? I have tried to solve it via completing the square and using the quadratic formula, and got different answers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$z(z+i)=0$ so $z=0$ or $z=-i$.

Comment: Too simple. Thanks!